# how to pass structure to function?

Tags: c++, function, struct

here is what i am trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>

void out(box boxx);
struct box {
    char charr;
    float floatt;
};

int main()
{
    box boxx;
    boxx.charr = 'f';
    boxx.floatt = 2.5;
    out(boxx);
}

void out(box boxx)
{
    std::cout << boxx.charr << "\n" << boxx.floatt;
}
```

I want to make a function that prints data from a structure.

Comment: You need to define (or at least declare) the structure box before the function declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move function declaration to after struct.

```
 #include <iostream>

 
 struct box {
 char charr;
 float floatt;
 };
void out(box boxx);
int main()
{
  box boxx;
 boxx.charr = 'f';
 boxx.floatt = 2.5;
 out(boxx);
}

void out(box boxx)
{
 std::cout << boxx.charr << "\n" << boxx.floatt;
}
```